# GeoPoints cercanos con firestore

Tags: firebase, geolocalización

El tema es que quiero una funcion de firebase, en el que se le pase un geopoint (latitud y longitud) y a partir de esta, me encuentre los lugares cercanos que yo tengo en la BBDD.

Lo único que tengo es esta ecuación:

```
(lonBD−lonCliente)^2+(latBD−latCliente)^2 < (20Km)^2
```

Donde 20km no va en km, van unidades que son 111 km cada unidad. Por lo tanto son 20/11 = 0'180 periodo

```
(lonBD−lonCliente)^2+(latBD−latCliente)^2 < (0'180)^2
```

El tema es que no quiero recorrer todas las filas de la base de datos. Creo que lo mejor serìa que esta formula fuera el `where` de la consulta.
Pero soy incapaz de encontrar el `Math.pow` o como  multiplicar para construir el where en  firestore.

Por lo pronto tengo esto, que claro está, no funciona:

```
module.exports = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   var firestore = admin.firestore();
   var latCliente = req.query.lat;
   var lonCliente = req.query.lon;
   firestore.collection('sitios')
     .where("(geo_coor.getLongitude()−lonCliente) * (geo_coor.getLongitude()−lonCliente) + (geo_coor.getLatitude−latCliente) * (geo_coor.getLatitude−latCliente)", "<", 0.03314)
     .get()
     .then(function(querySnapshot) {
         //console.log(querySnapshot.docs[0].data())
         res.jsonp(querySnapshot.docs.map(function (documentSnapshot) {
            return documentSnapshot.data();
         }));
     });
 });
```

Y el contenido de la BD es:
[image: base de dato donde la columna es geo_color con latitudes y longitude como subcolumnas]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el momento no se puede realizar la consulta tal cual quieres realizar, en la documentación el tipo GeoPoint, solo permite la función de igualación:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.GeoPoint

Igual como referencia existe esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46630752/5982279

Te recomiendo que utilices esta lib: https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib
(método findNearest), sin embargo como mencionas, tendrás que recorrer todo el conjunto de datos.

**ACTUALIZACION** (código de ejemplo):

```
import * as geolib from 'geolib';
        //...
        const sitioActual = {latitude:req.query.lat, longitude:req.query.lon};
        console.log("sitioActual",sitioActual);

        const coords:geolib.PositionAsDecimal = sitioActual;

        console.log("coords",coords);

        db.collection('sitios').get()
        .then((snapshot) => {

            const sitiosActuales:geolib.PositionAsDecimal[] = [];

            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                sitiosActuales.push( doc.data().coords );
            });

            console.log("sitiosActuales",sitiosActuales);

            const lugaresMasCercanos:geolib.Distance = geolib.findNearest(coords, sitiosActuales, 1);
            console.log("lugaresMasCercanos",lugaresMasCercanos);

            if(lugaresMasCercanos){

                console.log("Aquí verás los lugares Mas Cercanos",lugaresMasCercanos);

            }else{
                console.log('No existen lugares cercanos');
             }

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error en consulta: ', err);
            //Maneja tu error de la consulta aquí
        });
```

Comment: Tendras mayor posibilidad que se aceptada la respuesta si pones un ejemplo con código

Comment: Gracias, ya se colocó ejemplo de la alternativa con Geolib, ya que firebase carece de ese criterio de búsqueda por geoPoint.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @LeonardoG. Actualmente, no continuo don el proyecto. Pero si como dices, no se puede, la alternativa que comentas creo que sera de buena ayuda para el que venga buscando ayuda